# Any good online courses

Tags: calculus

Next year I start math at college and I am feeling quite unproductive this summer, I was wondering whether I could get some recommendation of free online math courses that could be helpful during my first year. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://aimath.org/textbooks/approved-textbooks/

Answer (score 2):

You did not specify what level you are interested in, but there are many excellent online math courses.

Examples include, but are not limited to:

- [*MIT Open Courseware*](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/)
- [*Khan Academy*](https://www.khanacademy.org/)
- [*Art of Problem Solving*](https://artofproblemsolving.com/)
- [*EdX*](https://www.edx.org/course/subject/math)
- [*Open Education Database*](https://oedb.org/open/subjects/math/)
- [*Open Culture*](http://www.openculture.com/math_free_courses)

There are also many free books available online that you can peruse.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following online courses for College level mathematics:
1. Linear Algebra by Gilbert Strang on MIT Open Courseware.
2. Abstract algebra by Ben Garson. This is a playlist on youtube.
Also, there are many good calculus resources on youtube. Khan academy would be a good starting resource for calculus of one and several variables. Hope this helps.